# Get tone number from pinyin

Tags: python, ascii

Say I have a pinyin:

```
gēge
```

How could I get the "tone number" of the accented character? 
eg,in this case, ē would be first tone, ideal output would be ge1ge. But really, first step is just how would I convert the tone into a number?

Example input / output:

```
gēge
nǎinai
wàipó
```

BECOMES

```
ge1ge
na3inai
wa4ipo2
```

I would like to do this ideally in python, but im flexible.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Ascii doesn't have accents!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When expressed in normal form D (*) (decomposition), the four pinyin tone use the following combining (unicode) signs:

- COMBINING MACRON (`'\u0304'`) for tone 1
- COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (`'\u0301'`) for tone 2
- COMBINING CARON (`'\u030c'`) for tone 3
- COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT (`'\u0300'`) for tone 4

That means that automatic processing in Python is almost trivial: you normalize your (unicode) string into its normal form D and replace the above combining characters with their digit value

Code could be:

```
def to_tone_number(s):
    table = {0x304: ord('1'), 0x301: ord('2'), 0x30c: ord('3'),
         0x300: ord('4')}
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s).translate(table)
```

You can then use:

```
>>> print(to_tone_number('''gēge
nǎinai
wàipó'''))
ge1ge
na3inai
wa4ipo2
```

in Python 3, or in Python 2:

```
>>> print(to_tone_number(u'''g\u0113ge
n\u01ceinai
w\xe0ip\xf3'''))
ge1ge
na3inai
wa4ipo2
```

---

(*) Refs:

- [module unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) in Python standard library reference manual
- [Pinyin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin#Using_tone_colors) on wikipedia

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to get at :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. There is a useful regex command:

```
re.findall()
```

You could use it first to identify all accented characters, and afterwords replace them with the string replace method,

```
str.replace('ē','e3')
```

for example

Comment: I wish it was that simple. There are many combinations of accented characters, and i cant be typing every single toned character to replace it with the normal version of it now can i?

Comment: There are 21 initials and 6 finals. Each with 4 tones thats 108 manual encodings @abccd

Comment: There's no better way, you can download a module off pypi but that's what they do as well